# What are the main denominations in the world practicing seventh-day Sabbatarianism? What percentage of Christendom do they represent?

Tags: comparative-christianity, resource-request, sabbath

I would like to know if there are reputable sources presenting anything close to an exhaustive listing of the main denominations around the world adhering to seventh-day Sabbatarianism. Similarly, are there recent studies estimating the percentage of Christendom that practices seventh-day Sabbatarianism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the largest seventh day sabbatarian churches are the [Seventh Day Adventist church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh-day_Adventist_Church) which has approximately 21 million members, and the [Seventh Day Baptist churches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh_Day_Baptists) with approximately 50,000 members worldwide.

This means they represent about 1% of Christians

Comment: *"By far the largest seventh day sabbatarian churches are [...] "* drawing on my common sense I'm biased to agree, but a reputable source backing up this claim would certainly be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the churches main website: [Seventh-day Adventist World Church Statistics 2018](https://www.adventist.org/church/statistics/).

And some other data that will get more granular: [Browse by Adventist World Divisions](https://www.adventiststatistics.org/).

This is limited to the Seventh-day Adventist numbers, but they are the largest group of Sabbatarians.